# Properties of the collection of maximal independent sets of a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, extremal-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph and define

$\mathscr{I}(G) = \{S \subset V(G)| S$ is a maximal indepedent set of $ G\}$

<del>1. What is known about $\mathscr{I}(G)$?</del>

2. What are some of the properties of $\mathscr{I}(G)$?
3. How does $\mathscr{I}(G)$ relates to other properties of $G$ for example chromatic number?
4. Is it possible to decide if a collection $\mathscr{A}$ is equal to $\mathscr{I}(H)$ for some graph $H$( is there a set of conditions on $\mathscr{A}$ to tell)?

Comment: 1 and 2 seem to be the same.  For 3 it is clear that the chromatic number (in fact, the chromatic polynomial) is a function of $\mathscr{I}(G)$.  Question 4 is easy: make the graph whose edges are the pairs of vertices that don't lie in the same member of $\mathscr{I}(G)$ and check that the independent sets are maximal.

Comment: Something can be said about the size: $|\mathscr{I}(G)|\leq3^{|G|/3}$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay, can you please elaborate on your comments about point 3. As for 4, I am more interested in a characterization ( a set of condition on the collection to tell) not the algorithmic aspect.

Comment: For 4, we may assume that no element of $\mathcal{A}$ is a subset of some other element. It is necessary and sufficient for $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{I}(G)$ (for some $G$) that every minimal set of vertices not contained in some element of $\mathcal{A}$ has two elements. Although this is little more than a restatement of the definition of $\mathcal{I}(G)$, I doubt whether one can do better.

Comment: For 3, the chromatic number equals the least number of maximal independent sets that cover everything. It's just the definition of $\chi(G)$ without mentioning $G$.